# Reverse of addr2line

Tags: assembly, dwarf, addr2line

given an object file and address addr2line tool can relate it to a file and line number in the source code.

I'd like to have the opposite. Given a line number and an object file I want to get a list of instruction addresses which correspond to a given line in the source code.

I know that I can use objdump -DS and seek for a line, but that inconvenient, and requires manual effort to filter out the addresses. Do you know any tool which can do what I want if I give it a list of lines?

UPD.

I give an example of what I want.

I have a set of file lines:

```
src/a.c:14
src/a.c:28
src/b.c:44
```

I pass this list to a tool:

```
cat lines | line2addr -e lib.so
```

And it reports me instruction addresses for these lines:

```
0x442: src/a.c:14
0x444: src/a.c:14
0x44a: src/a.c:14
0x584: src/a.c:28
0x588: src/a.c:28
...
```

Comment: The `gdb` debugger can do this with the executable (not individual object files). And of course, you'll need to compile with debug information ..

Comment: http://gcc.godbolt.org/ does a nice job for small functions of mapping lines to asm.  It even has color-coding.  e.g. http://goo.gl/aLPTts

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I can compile with debugging information. But I did not completely understand how can I get the addresses in gdb. I found out that I can set up a breakpoint, but it only shows me one address, although there can be several instructions for the same line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to do it in a utility manner is with the following GDB cmd-line:

```
gdb ../main.o -ex "info line main.c:39" --batch 
Line 39 of "main.c" starts at address 0x36 <main+54> and ends at 0x5e <main+94>.
```

The GDB accepts either an object or an executable file compiled with debug info `(-g)`. Use GDB 7.6 and higher. Earlier versions crashed on Windows while loading object files.

Multiple lines can be translated by applying the `-ex` switch multiple times:

```
gdb ../main.o -ex "info line main.c:39" -ex "info line main.c:41" --batch
Line 39 of "main.c" starts at address 0x36 <main+54> and ends at 0x5e <main+94>.
Line 41 of "main.c" starts at address 0x5e <main+94> and ends at 0x70 <main+112>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully the [documentation of *GDB*](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html). If your executable has been built with debug information (all code compiled with `-g`), you could use
[*stack* related](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Stack.html) commands, [*machine code* related](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Machine-Code.html) commands, etc.

I'm not sure to understand your wish, but I guess that `dis` and `x` commands could be helpful

In addition, recent GDB is scriptable in Python and Guile.

Comment: Updated the question with an example